# How to raise log level to error in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, logging

I have tried to suppress log by `spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")` in:

```
package com.databricks.example

import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession



object DFUtils extends Serializable {
  @transient lazy val logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass.getName)

  def pointlessUDF(raw: String) = {
    raw
  }

}

object DataFrameExample extends Serializable {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val pathToDataFolder = args(0)
    // println(pathToDataFolder + "data.json")

    // start up the SparkSession
    // along with explicitly setting a given config
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Spark Example")
      .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "/user/hive/warehouse")    
      .getOrCreate()

    // for suppresse logs by raising log level    
    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    // println(spark.range(1, 2000).count());

    // udf registration
    spark.udf.register("myUDF", DFUtils.pointlessUDF(_:String):String)
    val df = spark.read.json(pathToDataFolder + "data.json")
    df.printSchema()
    // df.collect.foreach(println)
    // val x = df.select("value").foreach(x => println(x));
    val manipulated = df.groupBy("grouping").sum().collect().foreach(x => println(x))    
    // val manipulated = df.groupBy(expr("myUDF(group)")).sum().collect().foreach(x => println(x))
  }
}
```

Why do I still get INFO and WARN level logs? Have I successfully raised log level to error? Thanks.

```
$ ~/programs/spark/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit    --class com.databricks.example.DataFrameExample    --master local target/scala-2.11/example_2.11-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar  /tmp/test/
20/03/19 10:09:10 WARN Utils: Your hostname, ocean resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 192.168.122.1 instead (on interface virbr0)
20/03/19 10:09:10 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
20/03/19 10:09:11 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
20/03/19 10:09:12 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.4.5
20/03/19 10:09:12 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application: Spark Example
20/03/19 10:09:12 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: t
20/03/19 10:09:12 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: t
20/03/19 10:09:12 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
20/03/19 10:09:12 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
20/03/19 10:09:12 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(t); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(t); groups with modify permissions: Set()
20/03/19 10:09:13 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 35821.
20/03/19 10:09:13 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
20/03/19 10:09:13 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
20/03/19 10:09:13 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
20/03/19 10:09:13 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
20/03/19 10:09:13 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-ce47f30a-ee1c-44a8-9f5b-204905ee3b2d
20/03/19 10:09:13 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 366.3 MB
20/03/19 10:09:13 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
20/03/19 10:09:14 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
20/03/19 10:09:14 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://192.168.122.1:4040
20/03/19 10:09:14 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/tmp/test/bookexample/target/scala-2.11/example_2.11-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar at spark://192.168.122.1:35821/jars/example_2.11-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar with timestamp 1584626954295
20/03/19 10:09:14 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost
20/03/19 10:09:14 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 39215.
20/03/19 10:09:14 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 192.168.122.1:39215
20/03/19 10:09:14 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
20/03/19 10:09:14 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.122.1, 39215, None)
20/03/19 10:09:14 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 192.168.122.1:39215 with 366.3 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.122.1, 39215, None)
20/03/19 10:09:14 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.122.1, 39215, None)
20/03/19 10:09:14 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.122.1, 39215, None)
root
 |-- grouping: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: long (nullable = true)

[group_3,10]
[group_1,12]
[group_2,5]
[group_4,2]
```

Comment: All those logs were written before that line got executed. You may want to give it a look to 
[this](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#configuring-logging) to configure the log level before starting the application.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a `log4j.properties` file into your resources folder. Otherwise it would use the default settings that are set in your spark folder. On Linux usually here: `/etc/spark2/.../log4j-defaults.properties`).

The location is also mentioned in your log file:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
```

Make sure to set the `rootCategory` to `ERROR`, like in the following example:

```sh
# Set everything to be logged to the console
log4j.rootCategory=ERROR, console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n
```